# how to delete multiple rows in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have to delete last three rows of the array. It was list but I had to convert it into array so that I can use np.delete function

I tried np.delete function. It deletes column wise instead of row wise.

I want to delete row not column. When I change the axis to 1. it gives an error message of AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

`featureStr2=np.delete(f, slice(3,-1), axis=0)`. I want to delete last 3 rows. Array looks like below

```
1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 20

11 23 54 6 7

2 3 4 5 6 7

1 2 3 4 5
```

Out put of the code is. I want output to delete last 3 rows.

Comment: Could you please add you code with this question?

Answer (score 2):

Don't delete in numpy. Deleting triggers a reallocation, which is expensive. The cheap (proper) solution is to just create a view using indexing:

```
 arr = arr[:-3, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

## you can drop rows by using pandas with drop, indexing and condition function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = ([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,20],[11,23,54,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3,4,5])
series = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

## by using drop function

```
series1 = series.drop([2,3,4])
print(series1)
```

## using index function

```
series1 = series.drop(series.index[2,3,4]
print(series1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Axis and object:

Syntax: `numpy.delete(arr, obj, axis=None)`

object : is the row number or column number or a indices

Axis: 0 for the rows and 1 for the columns

e.g. i'm assuming your array looks like this.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,4,5,6,7], [3,4,5,6,7], [5,7,8,9,1]])
>>> np.delete(a, [2,3], axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

P.S. for now np.delete doesn't support negative indices, in future it will , so i suggest you to get the indices of the rows you want to delete first and then pass it to obj in np.delete()

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just use basic indexing

```
>>>import numpy as np

>>>arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 20], [11, 23, 54, 6, 7], 
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7],[1,2, 3, 4, 5]])

>>>arr = arr[:-3]

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 20]])
```

np.delete(arr, obj, axis=None) doesn't take in negative indices in its object argument

Also, if array size is large, then supplying index of every row, column or element to be deleted becomes tedious.

```
>>>np.delete(arr, [2,3,4], axis=0) 

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 20]])
```

But by using `np.s_` you can supply a slice to the function

```
>>>np.delete(arr, np.s_[2:5], axis=0)

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 20]])
```

You can supply negative indexing to `np.s_`

```
>>>np.delete(arr, np.s_[-3:], axis=0)

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 20]])
```